# Projection to get distance from plane to point

Tags: linear-algebra

The equation $2x_1 - 3x_2 -6x_3 = -4$ defines a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$

I know the normal vector $\bf a$ for this is $(2,-3,-6)$

I am trying to find the distance from the point ${\bf w} = (3,-3, 5)$ to the plane by using projection. I have tried using $proj_aw$ this give me a answer that doesn't really make sense.I also have tried getting it parametrically but that keeps giving me a negative answer

Comment: You need to find the vector normal to the plane that ends at the point $w$. The length of this vector is the distance your after. You can use the projection to find this.

Comment: Would I just multiply the normal vector by some variable t to be able to do this?

Comment: No, if you sketch some of the vectors you will see you can make a triangle. One of the sides of this triangle is the distance you want.

Comment: Ok, i just want to confirm, the answer i get doing that is 45, does that sound right?

Answer (score 0):

The length of $a$ is $7$, so the distance of $w$ to the plane given by 
$$|\frac17\langle a,w\rangle+\frac 47|.$$